# WooCommerce product categories in main menu

Tags: woocommerce, categories

I'm using WooCommerce with already defined 3-level categories.

Everything works well, the category and sub-category list is well structured in the product categories page the new product creation page, except for the menu editing page.

I have all the categories and sub-categories but without their original structure (some of them preserved their structure but all the others got aligned into one level), so when adding them to the menu, I will not be able to tell which sub-category belongs to which category.

Is there a way to refresh or remap the full structure?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create a menu in WordPress admin menu, blank menu. Now go to the `function.php` file (theme file) add the following code in it.

You can get the products category list from this function:

```php
function get_product_terms( $term_id ) {    
        $html = '';    
        $args = array( 'hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' => $term_id );    
        $terms = get_terms('product_cat', $args);

        foreach ($terms as $term) {    
            $html .= '<li';    
            if( $term_id == 0 ) {    
                $html .= ' class="top_li"';    
            }

            $html .= '><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'product_cat').'">' . $term->name . '</a>';    

            if( $list = get_product_terms( $term->term_id )) {    
                $html .= '<ul class="second_level">'.$list.'</ul>';    
            }

            $html .= '</li>';    
        }    
        return $html;    
    }
```

You can add the products category to the menu using this function:

```php
// Filter wp_nav_menu() to add additional links and other output
function new_nav_menu_items($items) {
    // Woo function

    /*//product_cat
    $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
    print_r($terms);*/
    if( $list = get_product_terms( 0 )) {



    $menu1link = '<li class="home"><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . __($list) . '</a></li>';
    $homelink = '<li class="home"><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . __('Home') . '</a></li>';
    // add the home link to the end of the menu
    $items = $items . $homelink;
    $items = $items .$menu1link;
    }
    return $items;

}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items' );
```

Comment: I didn't see a menu name. can you please mention either the name of menu should i create in the admin or comment the where we get the blank menu name to insert all the menu list?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does not allow menus to inherit structure from another component.

Menus are supposed to have a stand alone, separate, structure and are not supposed to know anything about your category structure.

So the answer is no, you'll have to do that yourself. You could build a script that includes every added category to a menu in a way that you end up with the same structure, but I DO NOT recommend that. Since the possibility for error would be huge.